# Eclipse (php) always crashes EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: eclipse, ide, fatal-error, php-ide

Im not so familiar in eclipse and new of it.

This is the **error log file**

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0xffffffffa5795120, pid=4680, tid=0x00000000000009f8

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  0xffffffffa5795120

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

I already searched here in stackoverflow and tried put this on eclipse.ini

```
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.TypeConverter::*
```

still my eclipse crashes